# Is WI-FI available in Lyon Airport upon arrivals?

Tags: france, airports, lyon

I'd be arriving on Lyon saint exupery airport tomorrow night and I wanted to know if there are Wi-Fi facilities available there upon arrival? I researched online but really couldn't come up with a consolidated answer.

If you have a recent experience landing at Lyon airport, can you please let me know if there are internet/Wi-Fi facilities in the arrival halls.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there's [free wifi](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/france/lyon-saint-exupery-airport) in the [terminal areas](http://www.lyonaeroports.com/en/shopping-services/multimedia-services) and paid wifi in the [lounge areas](http://www.lyonaeroports.com/en/shopping-services/lounges) of terminals 1 and 2.

To get to the lounge area (they call them [service salon](https://lyonaeroports.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/639739-quelles-prestations-offre-le-service-salon)) you need to buy a [coupon](https://lyonaeroports.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/639721-qu-est-ce-que-le-service-salon) first, you can do it online or [in terminal 1](https://lyonaeroports.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/639751-puis-je-acheter-un-service-salon-sur-place).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to free WiFi at the airport, [there is free and usable WiFi on the airport tram](https://www.rhonexpress.fr/en/discovery/34).  This tram is currently the only reasonable public transport option to get into the city.  It takes about half an hour.